# Is $E((\Sigma_i^n u_i)^2) = 0$ or $n\sigma^2$ (in OLS)?

Tags: regression, least-squares, covariance

Consider an OLS estimator,
$$y= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + u_i $$

I think $E((\Sigma_i^n \: u_i)^2) $ is equal to zero because simply $\Sigma_i^n \: u_i$ is always zero.

But my professor in class showed it is equal to $n\sigma^2$. Here is the derivation assuming n=3.

$$
E((\Sigma_i^n \: u_i)^2) = E((u_1+u_2+u_3)^2) \\
E((\Sigma_i^n \: u_i)^2) = E(u_1^2+u^2_2 + u^2_3 + 2(u_1u_2+ u_2u_3 + u_3u_1) \\
E((\Sigma_i^n \: u_i)^2) = E(u_1^2)+E(u^2_2) + E(u^2_3) + E(u_1u_2) + E(u_2u_3) + E(u_3u_1) \\
E((\Sigma_i^n \: u_i)^2) =\sigma^2 + \sigma^2 +\sigma^2+ 0 +0+0 \\
E((\Sigma_i^n \: u_i)^2) = 3\sigma^2
$$

What am I missing here? Isn't $E(u_i, u_j)=0?$

Comment: Sum of the residuals is zero. But $u_i$'s are independent random errors, not residuals.

Comment: But still, the expectation of their sum should be zero, right?

Comment: Yes, but the expectation of the square of their sum is not equal to the square of the expectation of their sum: Jensen's Inequality and all that.

Answer (score 2):

A Sycorax already suggested, the confusion arises because the estimated residuals $e_i = Y_i-\hat{Y_i}$ are usually not equal to the true error terms $\epsilon_i$ (instead of $u_i$, I will use the symbol $\epsilon_i$ for the true unknown error terms). Suppose the true regression equation is $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \epsilon$. The "stupid" thing of OLS is that, in order to get to the estimates $\hat{b_0}$ and $\hat{b_1}$ of the unknown $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, it is decided to calculate these estimates in such a way that the sum, over all cases, of the squared $e_i$ terms is minimal, or $\Sigma e_i^2 = \Sigma (Y_i-\hat{Y_i})^2 = \Sigma [Y_i - (\hat{b_0}+\hat{b_1}X_i)]^2 $ is minimal, where the summation is over all cases in the sample. The consequence of this "stupid" criterion is that $\Sigma e_i=0$, which does not at all have to be the case for $\Sigma \epsilon_i$, being the sum of the true error terms of the cases in the sample.

To understand that for the true error terms $\epsilon_i$ the summation over all cases in the sample need not be zero, consider the following. Suppose I would show you a point diagram of $Y$ on the vertical axis against $X$ on the horizontal axis, **for all cases in the population**. Also, the true regression line (for the population) is shown in the diagram, and thus the (signed) vertical distance from each point to the line is known, i.e. the $\epsilon_i$ term is known. Next, you are asked to choose at random three points (cases) out of the diagram, and sum there $\epsilon_i$ terms, or their (signed) distances to the regression line. Would you then expect the sum to be equal to zero? Probably not, because that would be very coincidental! However, for a sample of exactly three cases, the tree estimated (not the true) residuals $Y-\hat{Y}$ would actually sum to zero!

Conclusion: the values of the estimated $\hat{b_0}$ and $\hat{b_1}$ are in general not equal to the true values of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ or: the estimated regression line is not equal to the true line (in the population). As a result, the estimated residuals $e_i$ are not equal to the true errors $\epsilon_i$. Also, they have the "stupid" property that they sum to zero across all cases in the sample.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown the case for $n=3$. The general case can be seen by using properties for the expectation and variance of a sum of variables. We have $E(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n E(u_i)= 0 $. Therefore,

\begin{align}
V\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\right)&= E\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\right)^2\right) - E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i \right)^2 \\
&= E\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\right)^2\right).
\end{align}

Since $E(u_i, u_j)=0, i \neq j$, then $V\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n V(u_i)= n \sigma^2$ and it follows that $E\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\right)^2\right) = n \sigma^2$.

As someone else mentioned, you must not confuse the errors $u_i$ with the residuals.

Comment: (+1) This answer could be improved if you articulated why the errors and the residuals are distinct, because that is a point of confusion for OP.